# edit cell in ag grid that I could edit number but not the sign near ir

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have number -10 in a cell and I want to edit it. When I click on the cell, number with a minus sign is highlighted. Is there a way that only number would be highlighted? Then I could write another number and sign remains. But if I would like to change a sign, then I would still be able to remove it manually.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In nutshell **target the input element and provide the custom cell selection range** [Plunker example link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PhCCyomTcUHPLUM7?open=main.js&preview)

```
onCellDoubleClicked: function (params) {
    var targetInput = params.event.target.querySelector('input')
    let value = targetInput.value;
    value.charAt(0) === '-' ? targetInput.setSelectionRange(1, value.length)    
                            : targetInput.setSelectionRange(0, value.length);
  }
```